# How to properly run PHP script in Pimcore?

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, pimcore

I'm trying to run my simple pimcore script using `bin/console pimcore:run-script script.php` command.
Code:

```
<?php
use \Pimcore\Model\Product;
namespace AppBundle\Command;
$user = \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Product::getById(88228);
echo $user->getId();
```

But it seems that there is no object with that id (but it exists):

```
Running script src/AppBundle/Command/script.php
15:02:25 WARNING   [cache] Failed to fetch key "object_88228" ["key" => "object_88228","exception" => Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException^ { …}]
15:02:25 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "pimcore:run-script 'src/AppBundle/Command/script.php'". Message: "Call to a member function getId() on null" ["exception" => Error { …},"command" => "pimcore:run-script 'src/AppBundle/Command/script.php'","message" => "Call to a member function getId() on null"]

In script.php line 5:
                                             
  Call to a member function getId() on null
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for help!

With verbose:

```
Exception trace:
  at /home/ec2-user/my-project/src/AppBundle/Command/script.php:5
 include() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/bundles/CoreBundle/Command/RunScriptCommand.php:48
 Pimcore\Bundle\CoreBundle\Command\RunScriptCommand->execute() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:1027
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:97
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:83
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/ec2-user/my-project/bin/console:36
```

Comment: Can you run the script with a verbose flag?

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: I don't know anything about pimcore although I work in Symfony all the time. I'm seeing the cache miss warning, and unless everything is preloaded I wouldn't expect that to be a warning level. I assume there's a datastore in some way, such as a database? Can you get some debugging to confirm that that is actually being invoked?

Comment: It looks like you are using
use \Pimcore\Model\Product;
But later \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Product
The DataObject is missing in the use statement. I guess Pimcore can not find the proper class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have DataObject of class Product with id 88228.
It is absolutely ok -- it can be deleted or unpublished.

Just add checking before to use the object:

```
$product = \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Product::getById(88228);
if ($product instanceof Product) {
    echo $product->getId();
}
```